# Dictionary comprehension and os.listdir() - python3

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary-comprehension

I have the following dictionary comprehension (first lines code group) created with the length and elements from the list *os.listdir('./foo')*. The resulting dictionary is not the one that I was expecting. Why does it is happening?

```
  >>>folder = {k : v for k in range(len(os.listdir('./foo'))) for v in os.listdir('./foo')}
  >>>print(folder)
  >>>{0: 'foo0', 1: 'foo0', 2: 'foo0', 3: 'foo0'}
```

but

```
>>>print(os.listdir('./foo'))
>>>{0: 'foo0', 1: 'foo1', 2: 'foo2', 3: 'foo3'}
```

so, I am expecting the following dictionary instead of the first one.

```
  >>>folder = {k : v for k in range(len(os.listdir('./foo'))) for v in os.listdir('./foo')}
  >>>print(folder)
  >>>{0: 'foo0', 1: 'foo1', 2: 'foo2', 3: 'foo3'}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are not doing the dict comprehension properly, you shouldnt have 2 different `for` statements. instead, use `zip`:

```
folder = {k : v for k,v in zip(range(len(os.listdir('./foo'))), os.listdir('./foo'))}
```

or even better, use `enumerate()`:

```
folder = {k : v for k,v in enumerate(os.listdir('./foo'))}
```

Comment: well yes, I guess that's not a very good way of saying that.  I will edit @MadPhysicist, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite your original comprehension as the nested `for` loops it logically (approximately) represents:

```
folder = {}
for v in os.listdir('./foo'):
    for k in range(len(os.listdir('./foo'))):
        folder[k] = v
```

Besides the fact that you call `os.listdir` repeatedly, you are inserting multiple items into the dictionary for each key. The correct comprehension would be something more like:

```
folder = {k: v for (k, v) in enumerate(os.listdir('./foo'))}
```

On a related note, the result of `os.listdir()` is a list, not a dictionary, so

```
>>> print(os.listdir('./foo'))
['foo0', 'foo1', 'foo2', 'foo3']
```

is a more likely scenario than what you posted.

Comment: I'm not so sure about the `if not k in folder` part. Last time I checked (5 minutes ago ;-)), the dictionary comprehension was *last assignment wins* when the comprehension produces duplicate keys. The output from `os.listdir()` isn't necessarily sorted, so it's kind of suggestive from the example in the question, though.

Comment: Good point. I overthought the reason for why the first file was showing up. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you got the semantics of the dictionary comprehension not quite right:

```
{k : v for k in range(len(os.listdir('./foo'))) for v in os.listdir('./foo')}
```

is equivalent to "*iterate over all `v` from `os.listdir()` and for every of these `v` iterate over all `k` from `range()`*.

Since a simple dictionary cannot hold duplicate `k`-`v`-pairs, the last assignment counts, hence the above is essentially equivalent to:

```
{k : os.listdir('./foo')[-1] for k in range(len(os.listdir('./foo')))}
```

Note that the semantics are the same as if the comprehension was written as

```
dict((k, v) for k in range(len(os.listdir('./foo'))) for v in os.listdir('./foo'))
```

None of these make sense out of context so you might want to add more information what you are actually trying to achieve.